# What's causing "Invalid index nn for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=nn" when a column is Null in the database?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nullable

For Accommodation entity we have two columns that are nullable: `CollectionType` and `AccommodationUnitType`.

However I noticed in the data that they were set to zero rather than null, causing NHibernate to try and find an entity with id 0. This was a lot of extra unnecessary DB calls, so I updated the relevant data to NULL in the database, and suddenly I get a big fat  error:

> "Invalid index 24 for this
>   SqlParameterCollection with Count=24"

Here is the mapping override I'm using:

```
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Core.Entities.Itinerary.Accommodation.Accommodation> mapping)
    {
        ...
        mapping.References(x => x.CollectionType).Nullable();//.Not.LazyLoad();
        mapping.References(x => x.AccommodationUnitType).Nullable();//.Not.LazyLoad();
        Cache.Is(c => c.ReadWrite());
    }
```

Google has lots of answers that don't seem to have anything to do with my problem.

Any ideas?

***Edit*** 
For info the properties are entities, so are nullable:

```
public virtual AccommodationUnitType AccommodationUnitType { get; set; }
public virtual AccommodationCollectionType CollectionType { get; set; }
```

Comment: post the resulting XML mappings.

Comment: Sorry didn't get notified of this comment, only just seen it. Thanks- it helped me to spot that I *also* had one of the ids mapped on the object without realising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are "CollectionType" and "AccommodationUnitType" both designated as "int"?

When working with nulls you would need to designate them both as "int?".

Not sure if this is the problem you are having but it corrected something similar for me.

```
public virtual int? CollectionType {get;set;}
public virtual int? AccommodationUnitType {get;set;}
```

Comment: Hi, actually no they're Entities of type AccommodationCollectionType and AccommodationUnitType respectively. Thanks though.

Comment: Actually, I just discovered I had one of the ids mapped too, and it wasn't nullable. Thanks!